Encounter Tomcat 10.1 error, not sure about my pom.xml setup is actually right
I try to run my app on tomcat 10.1 and i encounter this error
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [com.px.share.api.ApplicationConfig] threw exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/ws/rs/core/EntityPart


at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueParamProvider$MultipartFormParamValueProvider.<clinit>(FormParamValueParamProvider.java:245)

at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.FormParamValueParamProvider.<init>(FormParamValueParamProvider.java:82)

at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ValueParamProviderConfigurator.init(ValueParamProviderConfigurator.java:90)

at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ApplicationHandler.java:306)

at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4390)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:306)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:273)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:314)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:339)
at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:837)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4458)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:599)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:654)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:635)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:484)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1703)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:264)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:939)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:314)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:598)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:54)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:663)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.ws.rs.core.EntityPart
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1144)
        ... 62 more

This project already run on jarkata 10 EE Web and Java 11. I trying to modified pom.xml, but i'm not sure how i should modify my pom.xml or my tomcat to make it work
Here is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://www.maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.px</groupId>
    <artifactId>pxservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>pxservice</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <buildNumber>v.${project.version} build ${maven.build.timestamp}</buildNumber>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
            <name>Aspose Java API</name>
            <url>https://releases.aspose.com/java/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.8.0.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.security.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.security.enterprise-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20211205</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.olap4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>olap4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-cells</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-imaging</artifactId>
            <version>24.7.1</version>
            <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-slides</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <classifier>jdk16</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
            <artifactId>DynamicJasper</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <classifier>jdk17</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-words</artifactId>
            <version>24.7</version>
            <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>pxservice</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

My pom.xml look like it already meet everything that both jakarta 10 EE and Tomcat 10.1 needed, what do i overlook from my pom anyway?

Your error message:

exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
jakarta/ws/rs/core/EntityPart

Let’s talk about the conclusion first:
jakarta.ws.rs-api 3.0.0 does not have jakarta.ws.rs.core.EntityPart.class
REMOVE jakarta.ws.rs-api 3.0.0
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

ADD jakarta.ws.rs-api 4.0.0
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>

How to verify ?
Download Jar:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/4.0.0/jakarta.ws.rs-api-4.0.0.jar

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jakarta/ws/rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/3.0.0/jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.0.0.jar


Unzip Jar
Then Search EntityPart file in directory jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.0.0 and jakarta.ws.rs-api-4.0.0.
You won't find EntityPart in jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.0.0, but you can find EntityPart in jakarta.ws.rs-api-4.0.0.

jakarta.ws.rs-api-4.0.0 not compatible with my jdk and i find out that i can use jakarta.ws.rs-api-3.1.0 instead because it also have EntityPart
https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/3.1.0/jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta/ws/rs/core/package-summary.html

My personal practice is to use JDK 17 with Tomcat 10.1, Spring Boot 3.x, Jakarta EE 10.

Entity part solve, but got a new one, should i edit post or post a new question?

my project is migrating from tomcat 9 and jdk 11 so i'm trying to play safe

According to the convention of this site, it should be a question and a post.

ok, then i thick answer as accepting question and begin a new question, thank you very much.
